# $\langle f, v \rangle_{L^2(0,T;H'), L^2(0,T;H)}=0$ for all $v$ implies $f = 0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose that for some $f \in L^2(0,T;H')$,
$$\langle f, v \rangle_{L^2(0,T;H'), L^2(0,T;H)}=0$$ for all $v \in L^2(0,T;H).$

How do I show that this implies $f = 0$? $H$ is Hilbert.

Comment: I don't understand your notation, but what about taking $v=f$?

Comment: Well $f \in L^2(0,T;H')$ but v is only in $L^2(0,T;H)$. But I think maybe I can use Riesz representation theorem to give me what I need.